# Upgrading Microsoft.Bot.Builder.LanguageGeneration to 4.15.0 results in fromFile() error

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, nuget-package, fromfile

Upgrading `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.LanguageGeneration` from `4.14.1` to `4.15.0` results in new errors about the `fromFile()` method. Couldn't find any solution or similar issues on the internet yet. This holds us from upgrading so any feedback is welcome.

```
/UnitTests/bin/Debug/net5.0/Resources/Lg/General.lg line 25:2 - line 25:39: Error occurred when parsing expression 'fromFile('../Cards/HelpCard.json')'. fromFile does not have an evaluator, it's not a built-in function or a custom function.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This release introduces a global flag called
> "Templates.EnableFromFile" that indicates whether the Adaptive
> Expression fromFile function is allowed in LG templates. If an
> application had previously made use of this function, it is now
> required to add the line "Templates.EnableFromFile = true;" to the
> Startup.cs code.

from [botbuilder-dotnet/releases](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/releases)

Adding it in `Startup.cs` (or `Program.cs`) didn't help. I had to put it in the constructor of the service where I used the `Templates` class.

Comment: I couldn’t select my own answer as answer in the first 2 days for some reason. I’ll do it now 

Answer (score 1):

[image]

For someone who needs sample on how to add it.

Add it like this in startup.cs-> ConfigureServices method.

Also on lg file - you dont have to create manually lg file - it will be generated in backend.

You just have to add your content in bot responses which is the content it will be generated in lg file in backend - you can open the same solution in visual studio and see it.